Change Image In Wordpress by Click
My question is to create something in Wordpress.
I like to create a kind of advent calender. There are 25 small images an one big image. What i want to establish is when clicking one of the 25 small images, the big one will change accordingly. So, for instance, when clicking small image 7 (or text 7), the block with large image will show image LARGE07.PNG (or something like that).
Is there a way with php or so?
Thanks in advance for your help!
Hans
i havent tried a php-code or working with an url-parameter or shortcode.

that means you have each small images in 2 versions, open and close ? then you have 50 small images and 25 large images ? to store the progression of the user in database, you can use this : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_user_meta/

actually perhaps yes, normal small images (with a click option) and greyed-out images (without click-option). Perhaps i can handle that manually. The big question for me is how to change the BIG image when clicking a small small image.
So yes, there are also 25 large images.
Thanks for the link, i will study it!!

if it's the first time you develop a plugin for wordpress, start to read this https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/

not really my first attempt to create a plugin. I am not a professional programmer, so i am just looking for some code to change a picture by clicking something else than the picture itself.

the php code will not change pictures, it will just generate something else. e.g. it's the day 12, the code show the picture 11. the user click on 12, the code save the value 12 and then the page is refreshed and the code show the picture 12.

I created this shortcode which is (in short) the solution for me
add_shortcode('myImage', 'myImage');
function myImage($atts, $content = null) {
extract( shortcode_atts( array(
'name' => ''
), $atts ) );
$name = isset($_GET['n']) ? $_GET['n'] : '';
return '';
}
